# Postgres character with byte sequence 0xe2 0x80 0x99 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1

Tags: postgresql

Query failed: ERROR: character with byte sequence 0xe2 0x80 0x99 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1" postgres for specific table
getting this error on specific table , how can we update character encoding for specific table in postgres?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the database encoding, and you cannot convert this character to `LATIN1`. Your options are:

- use a different client encoding
- use a different character in the database (`UPDATE`)

Comment: we are getting issue with only specific table not in entire database. How can we update client encoding of such table?

Comment: You change the client encoding of your database connection, not of the table.